Removing beforeEach breaks ionic jasmine tests
Same code, one with beforeEach and the other one without. The second breaks. I want to understand why...
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TestBedHelper } from 'src/app/helpers/tests/testbedhelper';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

describe('LoginPage', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPage>;
  let router: Router
  let mockGetStorage: any = null

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginPage],
      imports: [FormsModule, IonicModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
      providers: [TestBedHelper.mockStorage(mockGetStorage)]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router)
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be able to login', () => {
    const emailInput = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#email-input');
    const passwordInput = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#password-input');
    const emailLoginButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#email-login-button');
  
    emailInput.value = 'john.doe@example.com';
    emailInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('ionInput'))
    passwordInput.value = 'dummy1234';
    passwordInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('ionInput'));

    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(emailLoginButton.disabled).toBeFalsy()
  })
});

If I change my code to this:
  it('should be able to login', async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginPage],
      imports: [FormsModule, IonicModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
      providers: [TestBedHelper.mockStorage(mockGetStorage)]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router)
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const emailInput = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#email-input');
    const passwordInput = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#password-input');
    const emailLoginButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#email-login-button');
  
    emailInput.value = 'john.doe@example.com';
    emailInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('ionInput'))
    passwordInput.value = 'dummy1234';
    passwordInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('ionInput'));

    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(emailLoginButton.disabled).toBeFalsy()
  })
});


It fails with the following error:
        Expected true to be falsy.                                                                                                                                                            
            at <Jasmine>                                                                                                                                                                      
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/pages/session/login/login.page.spec.ts:35:39)                                                                                                 
            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)                                                                                                                                                   
            at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)                                                                                           
            at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)   

The button code is as follows:
          <ion-button
              id="email-login-button"
              size="large"
              expand="block"
              (click)="emailLogin()"
              [disabled]="validateForm()">
            Sing in
          </ion-button>


and the validateForm is:
  validateForm(): boolean {
    return !this.email || !this.password
  }


What am I missing? I have being banging my head against a wall for hours now...
The reason why I want this to work is to be able to use different mocks for my storage

I don't think it's realted to how you write your tests, but rather what you test.
Whan you set a value like you do (without using Angular), Angular itself is not aware of the changes on the component.
If you do that, is the test still erroring ?

However this is taken from the Angular documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78524173/removing-beforeeach-breaks-ionic-jasmine-tests
Also why does it work with beforeEach but it doesn't when I add it all in a single "it" function

Might be an issue with change detection. Try fixture.detectChanges() and then fixture.whenStable(() => {...expect()...})

Thanks for your answer! That didn't work either... forgot to mention I tried it before as well. Now just to make sure I retried but still no luck
